# Myfaces Tomahawk isn't working

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces, tomahawk

I'm trying use selectManyCheckbox of tomahawk but it doesn't works, I get this message in my web application:

> Warning: The page /resources/components/tabs/abaEdicaoFuncoesFuncionario.xhtml declares namespace http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk and uses the tag t:selectManyCheckbox , but no TagLibrary associated to namespace.

[image: tomahawk message]

I'm using selectManyCheckbox here:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">
<ui:component>
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="hrgi-div-form clearfix tamanho-aba-cadastro">
    <t:selectManyCheckbox id="selectFuncoes" value="#{funcionario.funcoes}" layoutWidth="2">
        <f:selectItems value="#{carregadorFuncoesFuncionario.itens}" />
    </t:selectManyCheckbox>
</h:panelGroup>
</ui:component>
</html>
```

and configured web.xml this way:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
        <param-value>20m</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I'm using Tomahawk 1.1.11, myfaces 2.1.6 and primefaces 2.1.1
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using ["Tomahawk for JSF 2.0"](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/download.html) (and not for JSF 1.2) and that all the Tomahawk JAR files are been placed in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and that no errors/warnings related to this occur in the server logs.